# How to print the contents of a RichEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Ive made a small program, where you enter a bunch of stuff and it puts it into a rich edit, but now how would I print the contents of the rich edit?

I was thinking about `RichEdit1.print();`, but i dont know what to put in the brackets. The rich edit has 6 different margins (2 for each different item (Name, quantity and Price))

If someones willing to help, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a single parameter, a string containing the name of the print job. This name will appear in the print manager, if the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Print) is to be believed:

> Use Print to print the contents of a rich edit control. The Caption parameter specifies the title that appears in the print manager and on network title pages.

You also need to set `PageRect` before printing. This defines the page dimensions on the printer. You need to query the device capabilities for the chosen printer, and apply any margins. I do that with this helper function:

```
procedure PrintRichEdit(RichEdit: TRichEdit; const Caption: string; 
  const PrinterMargin: Integer);
//the units of TRichEdit.PageRect are pixels, units of PrinterMargin are mm
var
  PrinterHeight, PrinterWidth: Integer;
  LogPixels, PrinterTopLeft: TPoint;
  PageRect: TRect;
  Handle: HDC;
begin
  Handle := Printer.Handle;
  LogPixels := Point(GetDeviceCaps(Handle, LOGPIXELSX),
    GetDeviceCaps(Handle, LOGPIXELSY));
  PrinterTopLeft := Point(GetDeviceCaps(Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETX), 
    GetDeviceCaps(Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETY));
  PrinterWidth := Printer.PageWidth;
  PrinterHeight := Printer.PageHeight;
  PageRect.Left := Max(0, Round(PrinterMargin*LogPixels.X/25.4)
    - PrinterTopLeft.X);
  PageRect.Top := Max(0, Round(PrinterMargin*LogPixels.Y/25.4)
    - PrinterTopLeft.Y);
  PageRect.Right := PrinterWidth-PageRect.Left;
  PageRect.Bottom := PrinterHeight-PageRect.Top;
  if (PageRect.Left>=PageRect.Right) or (PageRect.Top>=PageRect.Bottom) then
    //the margins are too big
    PageRect := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  RichEdit.PageRect := PageRect;
  RichEdit.Print(Caption);
end;
```

Comment: I managed to print the contents, but more information came up on the paper about my printer, and it wasnt really to aligned XD

Comment: Hard to know what that means.